# When it is set both keyProperty and displayProperty, it creates same tags

Tags: ng-tags-input

my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/jTfGVSX3OjTcPU2UvrSE?p=preview

I set `keyProperty: “email”, displayProperty: “name”`.

If I input `hoge@fuga.com` and press Enter, it creates a tag having same email property as existing one. I expect the validation error occurs when I input.

In `ng-tags-input.js`, It compares `element[keyProperty]` and `obj[keyProperty]`.  So, it add tag because the input data does not have keyProperty.

```
self.findInObjectArray = function(array, obj, key, comparer) {
    var item = null;
    comparer = comparer || self.defaultComparer;

    array.some(function(element) {
        if (comparer(element[key], obj[key])) {
            item = element;
            return true;
        }
    });

    return item;
};
```

I’m making email suggestion using ngTagsInput. I think the keyProperty is email for not duplicate, but displays name  as tag’s label.  So I set both keyProperty and displayProperty.

Is there any good way to implement the email suggestion and tag input?